# VBA dictionary data type

Tags: excel, dictionary, key, vba

Many sources, e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234, claim the key of a dictionary can be of many data types beyond string. However, when I tried integers and dates as keys, it fails. Can someone explain?

I tried the answer of @Tim Williams below, it works. What I had before was

```
Private Sub trial()
Dim dict As New Dictionary

dt = 1
'vols.marketDate = Date
dict.Add dt, 4 'vols
c = dict(dt)
End Sub
```

Does my way of defining a dictionary make a difference compared to that of @Tim Williams?

---

The second part of my question has to do with the value of a dictionary. I ran the following VBA code, attempting to use a user defined structure as the value of a diction, and encountered the error message:
[image]

```
Public Type volSurface
    marketDate As Date
End Type


Private Sub trial()
Dim dict As New Dictionary, vols As volSurface

dt = 1
vol.marketDate = Date
dict.Add dt, vols
c = dict(dt)
End Sub
```

Does this mean I can not use a structure as a value in a dictionary or there is something else I did wrong? If it is the latter case, how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem here:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d, k
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    d.Add 1, 1
    d.Add "a", 2
    d.Add #1/2/1978#, 3
    d.Add CDbl(66), 4
    d.Add CSng(99), 5
    d.Add True, 6

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print TypeName(k), k, d(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Integer        1             1 
String        a              2 
Date          1/2/1978       3 
Double         66            4 
Single         99            5 
Boolean       True           6
```

If there's specific code you're having a problem with, the add that to your question.

Comment: I tried your sample. It works. I just added my original code in the question. Would you please take a look at the way I declare the dictionary? Is it valid?

Comment: Thank you, @Tim Williams. That is strange, it did not work before... I added a related second question, concerning the data type of the value of a dictionary. Would you mind taking a look at that question?

Comment: Use a Class instead of a Type.